# GENSIM LDA topics with no probability assigned to it

Tags: machine-learning, lda, topic-modeling, dimensionality-reduction, data-preprocessing

I'm using LDA to discover topics in a BOW dataset. As I was testing the installation of the GENSIM library, I found no issue in the results of the example in their website ( https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html ), each observation had a complete distribution of topics ( each row summed up to 1 ).

As I tried to find topics in my BOW dataset ( Bag of words matrix of (59892 observations and 50 words ), I found out that some observations did not have a complete distribution of topics such as the examples below:

```
npTopicsData[0]
array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.2406106 , 0.5301496 ,
       0.17539015, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
      dtype=float32)
npTopicsData[2]
array([0.0100033 , 0.0100017 , 0.01000299, 0.46430823, 0.01000567,
       0.34798136, 0.01000324, 0.11768189, 0.01000131, 0.01001031],
      dtype=float32)
npTopicsData[0].sum()
0.9461503
npTopicsData[2].sum()
1.0
```

letting you know that I have not set any value for the following optional parameter for the LDA object:

```
minimum_probability (float, optional) – Topics with a probability lower than this threshold will be filtered out.
```

What are the possibilities of this issue? Is there a parameter I should set to insure a complete distribution for each observation? any problems I should monitor in the BOW dataset?

I also have used `lda.get_document_topics(corpus)` to retrieve topics from the GENSIM object for the **training data** (instead of `vector = lda[unseen_doc]` for unseen data), is that the correct practice?

Answer (score 0):

The observation's incomplete topic distribution might have been solved by setting the following parameter in the GENSIM LDA object to 0 ( minimum_probability (float, optional) ).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).